# Найти сумму элемнтов главной диагонали квадратной матрицы, учитывать только те строки, которые начинаются с отрицательного элемента?

Tags: c++, массивы

Написал функцию:

```
int on_sum(int** ptrarray, int x)
{
    int sum_on = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        if (ptrarray[i]<0)
        {
            sum_on += ptrarray[i][i];
        }
    }
    cout << sum_on;
    return sum_on;
}
```

Не считает сумму, выводит 0. Подскажите ,пожалуйста, что исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что матрица x * x, а цикл только 1(надо 2) и проверка должна быть

```
 if (ptrarray[i][0] < 0)
```

UPD:

```
for(int i = 0; i < x;i++)
 for(int j = 0; j < x;j++)
{

   if(ptrarray[i][0] < 0 && i == j)
           sum_on += ptrarray[i][j];

}
```

Comment: я думал идея яснa,додумайте сами до конца,а не просто код копипастой вставляйте @МаксимСтороженко

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.